# How to fetch latest posts and specific post id at first in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there way to fetch latest posts with pagination And I also want a specific post to first position in returned collection.
I tried this...

```
Post::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'draft')->orWhere('status', 'published');
})
->orWhere('id', 21)
->with(['author.profile'])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(3);
```

In this query I do get the `21` post id but it is on 3rd page. I want to get it on first place. Please guide How can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just post with id = 21 or it can be for many other posts at onece ?

Comment: Many other posts including post id = 21

Comment: What about separating the query and then merge the two resulted collections ?

Comment: Yes, I just did that. But I was thinking to reduce queries for better optimized code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a raw statement in your orderBy

```
Post::orderBy(DB::raw('id = 5'), 'DESC')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
```

This is because mysql can use boolean expressions in order by statements

Answer (score 0):

By using eloquent you do like this

```
Post::where('id', '=', 21)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
```